# Error while executing Eigenfaces algorithm in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I have a problem with the code for Eigenfaces i've found on the OpenCV tutorial page.

The code is this, exactly the same you can find on the related page (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#eigenfaces-in-opencv):

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2011. Philipp Wagner <bytefish[at]gmx[dot]de>.
 * Released to public domain under terms of the BSD Simplified license.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *   * Neither the name of the organization nor the names of its contributors
 *     may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
 *     without specific prior written permission.
 *
 *   See <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license>
 */

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static Mat norm_0_255(InputArray _src) {
    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    // Create and return normalized image:
    Mat dst;
    switch(src.channels()) {
    case 1:
        cv::normalize(_src, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
        break;
    case 3:
        cv::normalize(_src, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC3);
        break;
    default:
        src.copyTo(dst);
        break;
    }
    return dst;
}

static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images, vector<int>& labels, char separator = ';') {
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
    if (!file) {
        string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
        CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
    }
    string line, path, classlabel;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        stringstream liness(line);
        getline(liness, path, separator);
        getline(liness, classlabel);
        if(!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) {
            images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
            labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    // Check for valid command line arguments, print usage
    // if no arguments were given.
    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <csv.ext> <output_folder> " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    string output_folder = ".";
    if (argc == 3) {
        output_folder = string(argv[2]);
    }
    // Get the path to your CSV.
    string fn_csv = string(argv[1]);
    // These vectors hold the images and corresponding labels.
    vector<Mat> images;
    vector<int> labels;
    // Read in the data. This can fail if no valid
    // input filename is given.
    try {
        read_csv(fn_csv, images, labels);
    } catch (cv::Exception& e) {
        cerr << "Error opening file \"" << fn_csv << "\". Reason: " << e.msg << endl;
        // nothing more we can do
        exit(1);
    }
    // Quit if there are not enough images for this demo.
    if(images.size() <= 1) {
        string error_message = "This demo needs at least 2 images to work. Please add more images to your data set!";
        CV_Error(CV_StsError, error_message);
    }
    // Get the height from the first image. We'll need this
    // later in code to reshape the images to their original
    // size:
    int height = images[0].rows;
    // The following lines simply get the last images from
    // your dataset and remove it from the vector. This is
    // done, so that the training data (which we learn the
    // cv::FaceRecognizer on) and the test data we test
    // the model with, do not overlap.
    Mat testSample = images[images.size() - 1];
    int testLabel = labels[labels.size() - 1];
    images.pop_back();
    labels.pop_back();
    // The following lines create an Eigenfaces model for
    // face recognition and train it with the images and
    // labels read from the given CSV file.
    // This here is a full PCA, if you just want to keep
    // 10 principal components (read Eigenfaces), then call
    // the factory method like this:
    //
    //      cv::createEigenFaceRecognizer(10);
    //
    // If you want to create a FaceRecognizer with a
    // confidence threshold (e.g. 123.0), call it with:
    //
    //      cv::createEigenFaceRecognizer(10, 123.0);
    //
    // If you want to use _all_ Eigenfaces and have a threshold,
    // then call the method like this:
    //
    //      cv::createEigenFaceRecognizer(0, 123.0);
    //
    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    model->train(images, labels); //<--ERROR!!
    // The following line predicts the label of a given
    // test image:
    int predictedLabel = model->predict(testSample);
    //
    // To get the confidence of a prediction call the model with:
    //
    //      int predictedLabel = -1;
    //      double confidence = 0.0;
    //      model->predict(testSample, predictedLabel, confidence);
    //
    string result_message = format("Predicted class = %d / Actual class = %d.", predictedLabel, testLabel);
    cout << result_message << endl;
    // Here is how to get the eigenvalues of this Eigenfaces model:
    Mat eigenvalues = model->getMat("eigenvalues");
    // And we can do the same to display the Eigenvectors (read Eigenfaces):
    Mat W = model->getMat("eigenvectors");
    // Get the sample mean from the training data
    Mat mean = model->getMat("mean");
    // Display or save:
    if(argc == 2) {
        imshow("mean", norm_0_255(mean.reshape(1, images[0].rows)));
    } else {
        imwrite(format("%s/mean.png", output_folder.c_str()), norm_0_255(mean.reshape(1, images[0].rows)));
    }
    // Display or save the Eigenfaces:
    for (int i = 0; i < min(10, W.cols); i++) {
        string msg = format("Eigenvalue #%d = %.5f", i, eigenvalues.at<double>(i));
        cout << msg << endl;
        // get eigenvector #i
        Mat ev = W.col(i).clone();
        // Reshape to original size & normalize to [0...255] for imshow.
        Mat grayscale = norm_0_255(ev.reshape(1, height));
        // Show the image & apply a Jet colormap for better sensing.
        Mat cgrayscale;
        applyColorMap(grayscale, cgrayscale, COLORMAP_JET);
        // Display or save:
        if(argc == 2) {
            imshow(format("eigenface_%d", i), cgrayscale);
        } else {
            imwrite(format("%s/eigenface_%d.png", output_folder.c_str(), i), norm_0_255(cgrayscale));
        }
    }

    // Display or save the image reconstruction at some predefined steps:
    for(int num_components = min(W.cols, 10); num_components < min(W.cols, 300); num_components+=15) {
        // slice the eigenvectors from the model
        Mat evs = Mat(W, Range::all(), Range(0, num_components));
        Mat projection = subspaceProject(evs, mean, images[0].reshape(1,1));
        Mat reconstruction = subspaceReconstruct(evs, mean, projection);
        // Normalize the result:
        reconstruction = norm_0_255(reconstruction.reshape(1, images[0].rows));
        // Display or save:
        if(argc == 2) {
            imshow(format("eigenface_reconstruction_%d", num_components), reconstruction);
        } else {
            imwrite(format("%s/eigenface_reconstruction_%d.png", output_folder.c_str(), num_components), reconstruction);
        }
    }
    // Display if we are not writing to an output folder:
    if(argc == 2) {
        waitKey(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to execute this code i get this error:

```
    OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed) in reshape, file /tmp/opencv-ppDuGa/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src
/matrix.cpp, line 802 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /tmp/opencv-ppDuGa/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:802: error: (-13) The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed in function reshape

Abort trap: 6
```

The error appears during the train phase (as i've reported on the code).

I'm using XCode on Mac with the last OS Yosemite, the dataset is AT&T Facedatabase that can be downloaded from here: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for eigen and fisherfaces, the images have to get 'flattened' to 1 single row, this is only possible, if your Mat is continuous. (lbph is not constraind this way)

but i'd rather suspect, that the resp. Mat was *empty*, because it was not an image at all.

please check your data again very carefully. does it contain non-images (like a .txt file) ?

you probably generated a csv file via the supplied python script. again, check the outcome.

when reading the csv, try to replace

```
images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
```

with:

```
Mat im = imread(path, 0);
if ( im.empty() )
{
     cerr << path << " was empty !" << endl;
     exit(-1);
}
if ( !im.isContinuous() )
{
     // .bmp files sometimes are 'padded' to multiples of 4
     // (some image editors like to do that)
     // if you end up here, try to:
     //   * convert your images to png, pbm or such
     //   * use im.clone(); instead (the deep copy will force continuity)
     //
     cerr << path << " was not continuous !" << endl;
     exit(-2);
}
images.push_back(im);
```